# strtotime and custom field value

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field of Due and am trying to display the date. It is stored as 20131209. I am using

```
<?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $Due ) ); ?>
```

but it just throws out December 1, 2013

Answer (score 1):

The following works correctly for me, returning "December 9, 2013" in my case.

```
$Due = '20131209';
echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $Due ) );
```

So either ...

1. `$Due` is not what you think it is
2. Or you have set a custom date format to an incorrect value